# Initialization of a boolean with a Boolean.FALSE/.TRUE - why?

Tags: java, boolean

In some of our companys projects code I often read something like this:

```
boolean foo = Boolean.FALSE;
```

Besides the fact that AFAIK I only have to initialize local variables in Java at all (no random values like in Pascal) and besides the fact that especially for booleans I often WANT to have an initialization, what do I miss here? Why not:

```
boolean foo = false;
```

I don't get it. And code analyzation tools like PMD and Findbugs mark it, too. But why?

Edit: 
Without really knowing much about the bytecode except that it is there I created an example class and decompiled it. The Boolean.FALSE went to:

```
0: getstatic #15 // Field java/lang/Boolean.FALSE:Ljava/lang/Boolean; 
3: invokevirtual #21 // Method java/lang/Boolean.booleanValue:()Z 
6: istore_1
```

The 'false' variant went to:

```
0: iconst_1 
1: istore_1
```

So without knowing too much about this, I'd guess that more statements means more time to execute so it's not only wrong but also slower in the long run.

Comment: The first one is just plain wrong usage. Although you could argue that any possible style that makes code even more verbose is almost **idiomatic** to Java.

Comment: This could be to make sure that if Boolean (back-end) ever changes, this will make sure the code always works..? It looks weird.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik why is it plain wrong usage?  One thing is that you don't _like_ it, but that doesn't make it _wrong_?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It is wrong in a similar sense as naming a variable in all uppercase is wrong.

Comment: IMHO, Some people find comfort in writing something they consider to be English-like with padding and complexity.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Such people should prefer `boolean returnValue = false`, though :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you can do better.  The uppercase here indicate a constant, which it is.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen And `foo` indicates... a variable, which it also is. Your point being...?

Comment: Or even `if (condition == true) { return true; } else if (condition == false) { return false; }` ;)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you do not make sense.  Is your problem now that `foo` is in lowercase instead of uppercase?!

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I implied that naming a variable in all uppercase is wrong. Do you disagree, perhaps?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, now THAT reads much more like English language than `return condition` --- especially if you are a professional politician!

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik would you agree that `public static final Boolean FALSE = new Boolean(false);`  is a declaration of a constant and not a variable?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No doubt about it---that's a constant, just like `foo` is a variable in OP's example. How that makes any of my statements wrong still escapes me, though.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Perhaps if you instead of being facetious tried to actually _explain_ what you mean - I still have no idea what you meant with "The first one is just plain wrong usage".

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I thought it was obvious, but let's try and make it even more so. Naming a var in all uppercase compiles, but is wrong from the standpoint of standard Java style. Same goes for using a literal instance of `Boolean` to initialize a primitive `boolean` through auto-unboxing.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik mind reading is not easy for everyone.  You seem to assume that `foo` is a constant and not a variable.   I'm not sure that assumption holds.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen,@MarkoTopolnik: I think you are are at cross-purposes: Marko meant that using 'Boolean.FALSE' instead of 'false' is like writing 'int FOO = 6' (instead of 'static final int FOO = 6') and Thorbjørn mapped this statement to the actual example code I gave. So I think you mean both the same :)

Comment: @Campfire Thank you for interjecting, that may indeed be what is going wrong here. I hope this clears things up for Thornbjørn, then. The example with var naming conventions is unrelated to OP's code; it is just an example of another instance of the same class of code problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
boolean foo = Boolean.FALSE;
```

This is strange and unnecessarily complicated code, written by someone who likely didn't know Java very well. You shouldn't write code like this, and PMD and FindBugs are right to mark this.

`Boolean.FALSE` is a `java.lang.Boolean` object that gets auto-unboxed; the compiler essentially translates this to:

```
boolean foo = Boolean.FALSE.booleanValue();
```

> I don't have to initialize variables in Java at all...

Member variables do not need to be initialized explicitly; if you don't, they'll be initialized with a default value (which is `false` in the case of `boolean`). Local variables do need to be explicitly initialized; if you try to use a local variable without initializing it, the compiler will give you an error.

Answer (score 3):

Both are same. but `boolean foo = false;` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

The style to use an auto-unboxed `Boolean` constant in fact meshes well with the overall oververbosity endemic to many Java projects. For example:

```
public boolean isItOrIsItNotTheValueWeExpect(String aStringParameterThatCouldBeNull) {
  boolean booleanReturnValue = Boolean.FALSE;
  if (aStringParameterThatCouldBeNull != null) {
    if (aStringParameterThatCouldBeNull.length() > 3) {
      booleanReturnValue = Boolean.TRUE;
    }
    else {
      booleanReturnValue = Boolean.FALSE;
    }
  }
  else if (aStringParameterThatCouldBeNull == null) {
    booleanReturnValue = Boolean.TRUE.booleanValue();
  }
  return booleanReturnValue;
}
```

Obviously, the code above would be much preferred to this unreadable mess:

```
public boolean validate(String s) {
  return s == null? true : s.length() > 3;
}
```

The very occurrence of a ternary operator is considered a transgression and some projects even have it flagged by CheckStyle.

If your projects conform to such stylistic guidelines as these, that could justify your suspicious line of code.

Comment: I have personally found that the ternary operator is too powerful - as it can introduce a fork in the program flow without explicitly being marked with the `if` keyword.  Conciseness does not imply maintainability.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen There you go then, you should enable the CheckStyle rule against ternary operators :)

Comment: Oh man, if someone took my ternaries away from me, I'd cry for days.

Comment: @yshavit I'd just quit :) Java is such an underfeatured language, the last we need is banning any one of those precious few that we got!

Answer (score 2):

There is no good reason to do this, it was probably just a novice Java programmer.  I wouldn't worry too much, just replace it with false.

At the same time, you can usually if not always arrange your code such that you never declare a variable you don't have the final value for, i.e., making your objects immutable, which makes them easier to think about.  What's the value of x? compared to What's the value of x between the calls to foo() and bar()?  The first is generally easier to answer.  This requires you to split up your classes along lines you might not be used to doing but I recommend at least trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference really although the 1st method won't work on a 1.4 or earlier JVM. The first is more convoluted since it is fetching the static value from the Boolean object and then relying on autoboxing (introduced in 1.5) to change it from a Boolean object to a boolean primitive) although I can't imagine it would ever make any speed difference.

Generally though if you are assuming a particular initial value for a variable then I would recommend initialising it rather than just declaring it as it makes the code more readable.

Comment: There actually is a difference. `Boolean.FALSE` is a Boolean object, `false` is a primitive of type boolean.

Comment: Hi Kiyura, I realised this after posting and edited to correct it.  Just makes the assignment even more convoluted.

Comment: @Kiyura yes, but since it's assinged to a primitive boolean, it will immediately be unboxed, so the net result is the same.  I wouldn't even be amazed if the compiler optimized this out.